# How to make a Macro parser in C++ project

Tags: c++, parsing, macros

in the project, there are a lot of macros
such as

```
#define a (b+c)
#define b (e+d)
```

sometimes you need to decide the actual value of a .
so i am wondering if there are any tools for doing that, calculating all the macros and give the actual value as comment: (like below)

```
#define a (b+c)  //a = 5
```

Are there any opensource project related on this macro parsing job?
thanx

Comment: In linux/g++ environment you can use `g++ -E file.cpp > output` and then check wherever you have used `a` or `b` as a macro. It will be substituted by its final value. This is a raw way of doing thing, but just an FYI.

Comment: There's "mcpp", a standalone preprocessor.

Comment: IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) will calculate those values for you if they can parse your project well - although this will not put that into comments.

Comment: INSERT_STANDARD_REPLY_MACROS_CONSIDERED_EVIL

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how such a tool could exist as a macro may have an argument that is only known during execution(for instance `#define sum(a,b) (a+b)`). As for the value during runtime - any reasonable debugger will handle that.